# Generating variables to be named, filled in and operated on the fly in Python

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, array, python-2.x

I am very new to Python and trying to refactor my code which is ripe for error.

Currently, I manually name a bunch of arrays:

```
open_cost_mat_train = np.array([])
closed_cost_mat_train = np.array([])
open_cost_mat_train_1 = np.array([])
closed_cost_mat_train_1 = np.array([])
open_cost_mat_train_2 = np.array([])
closed_cost_mat_train_2 = np.array([])
```

I then pass them to a function that fills the arrays in differently according to their number (e.g. `_1`, `_2`, and also if their name contains `open` or `closed`):

```
for i in xrange(10):    
    open_cost_mat_train = np.append(open_cost_mat_train,i)
    open_cost_mat_train_1 = np.append(open_cost_mat_train_1,i/3))
    open_cost_mat_train_2 = np.append(open_cost_mat_train_2,i*64))
    closed_cost_mat_train = np.append(closed_cost_mat_train,i*3)
    closed_cost_mat_train_1 = np.append(closed_cost_mat_train_1,i/5))
    closed_cost_mat_train_2 = np.append(closed_cost_mat_train_2,i*102))
```

I then generate output file paths which corresponds with those matrices:

```
open_cost_category_path = "openCostClassifier.dat"
closed_cost_category_path = "closedCostClassifier.dat"
open_cost_category_path_1 = "openCostClassifier_1.dat"
closed_cost_category_path_1 = "closedCostClassifier_1.dat"
open_cost_category_path_2 = "openCostClassifier_2.dat"
closed_cost_category_path_2 = "closedCostClassifier_2.dat"
```

And finally I pass those variables to a new function (not necessary to show this for sake of question:

```
csoaa_open = example(open_cost_mat_train,open_cost_category_path)
csoaa_closed = example(closed_cost_mat_train,closed_cost_category_path)
csoaa_open_1 =example(open_cost_mat_train_1,open_cost_category_path_1)
csoaa_closed_1 = example(closed_cost_mat_train_1,closed_cost_category_path_1)
csoaa_open_2 = example(open_cost_mat_train_2,open_cost_category_path_2)
csoaa_closed_2 = example(closed_cost_mat_train_2,closed_cost_category_path_2)
```

What am I doing wrong with my code and how can I improve how I do things? Because this is the way I have written a lot of my code and getting one variable wrong. Doing this, for instance, will mess up the whole of my code:

```
csoaa_closed_1 = example(closed_cost_mat_train_2,closed_cost_category_path_1)
```

Comment: Make list of arrays, and list of operations. Or list of (array, operation) pairs.

Comment: Better yet, since all are created similarly, make a function that get an operation and returns an array.

Comment: @Elazar could you post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as numpy goes, I can't say anything to that. 
But what I am generally missing from your Code is abstraction.

This makes your code unelegant - at best.

OOP ftw!

This comes with *ordinary* lists, but it helps to clarify:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


class Calculation:
    def __init__(self, name, fn):
        self._name = name
        self._filename = name + ".dat"
        self._array = []
        self._fn = fn

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self._filename

    @property
    def elements(self):
        return self._array[:]

    def add_element(self, element):
        self._array.append(self._fn(element))


def main():
    calculation_definitions = [("open_cost_mat_train", lambda x: x),
                               ("closed_cost_mat_train", lambda x: x/3)]
    calculations = [Calculation(d[0], d[1]) for d in calculation_definitions]
    for x in range(10):
        for calculation in calculations:
            calculation.add_element(x)

    for calculation in calculations:
        print("{} {}".format(calculation.filename, calculation.elements))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You have a `class` instead of a *plain* variable.
This helps you to encapsulate:

1) The name/filename (in case you need it somewhere else)

With the constructor, you are free to define a naming scheme for your files. For the sake of the example, I simply used ".dat" as a suffix.

2) The actual datastructure (here for the sake of the example a list named »array«)

3) The calculation function

This is, what OOP was invented for: keeping together data and functions, which work on that data.

In the `main`-function, you see, how you set up things:

1) the `calculation_definitions` are made of a simple tuple, holding the name as the first element and the function as a second element

2) the configuration of your "variables" is done via *list comprehension*

`calculations = [Calculation(d[0], d[1]) for d in calculation_definitions]`.

For more complex tuples, I would go with [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which allows you to reference the content of the tuple via proper names than *indices*, which would result in *better readable* code. But in this scenario, the indices do the trick.

Your `example`-function should take the list of `Calculation` objects as a parameter. And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little something to clean up the code.

The lines inside your `for` loop e.g

```
open_cost_mat_train = np.append(open_cost_mat_train,i)
```

do not require an assignment on the left, `np.append` modifies the array being passed in. I'm not sure if that's what you want, but maybe you should inspect the arrays after the loop to ensure they contain what you expect.

If you're worried about modifying arrays by mistake or require a original copy, it may be worth cloning them before running any operations on them.

`copy_array = original_array.copy()` will clone a numpy array.

Another way to verify you're passing the right parameters could be to check their names. They seem to be labelled logically with a number at the end, so it seems `closed_cost_mat_train_2` should always go with `closed_cost_category_path_2`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python), the `inspect` module looks like a good choice for this.

**Docs for the numpy functions:**

[1] [numpy.append](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

[2] [numpy.copy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. The above answer by @ThomasJunk is super valuable, I haven't yet applied OOP to Python but have experience in doing so in Java.

Here is how I refactored my code (this cut a ton of lines of code):

It all starts from generating the variables which are the names of the models:

```
for x in range(1,4):
        cost_matrices["open_cost_{0}".format(x)]=[]
        cost_matrices["closed_cost_{0}".format(x)]=[]
```

Then I can manipulate each cost matrix based on its key name:

```
def genCostMatrices(costMatrix):
    for i in xrange(10):
        for key, value in costMatrix.iteritems():
                if str(key).startswith("open"):
                    if str(key).endswith("1"):
                        value.append(i)
                    if str(key).endswith("2"):
                        value.append(i/3)
                    if str(key).endswith("3"):
                        value.append(i*2)
                else:
                    if str(key).endswith("1"):
                        value.append(i+4)
                    if str(key).endswith("2"):
                        value.append(i*8))
                    if str(key).endswith("3"):
                        value.append(i/9)
```

And similarly use those initial keys to apply other operations (e.g. naming output files):

```
paths = {}

    def generateDatPaths(model):
        paths[model]=os.path.join(model+".dat")

    for key in cost_matrices.keys():
        generateDatPaths(key)
```